# How to manage massive projects building

Tags: build, continuous-integration

**I wonder is there a way or a tool to manage central build efficiently?** I'm currently working on the task of improving the building process for our project. The task has two goals,

1. Speed up the building (it takes 12 hours to build the whole stuff right now)
2. Find a way to manage project's dependencies automatically (we use a master .cmd script to build all of the projects in the given order)

We have C++, Java, C# projects (70%,20%,10%). Most of them are built on Windows while rest of them are on Linux. The build script contains ant, msbuild call in everywhere.

A little bit mass, right? Any ideas?

Thanks, Miles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a source code repository on a build server? If not you might want to think about migrating your source repositories to a dedicated server. From there you can use either either MS build or ant to defined builds that are triggered when code is checked in. This will allow you to commit everything and get a nasty email if your code broke the build. Just kidding, but you will get messages stating that you broke the build. I have used Team City and Cruise Control with very good success. I don't remember a build taking 12 hrs. that may be the cpp files being made...who knows. Team City is very clean and leaves a zipped artifact file for each project build that on a given date that could be deployed for testing and so on. Perhaps you have a mammoth c++ projects in which case you may want to break it up into buildable chunk.

Comment: PS: We do have a repository, of course, p4... The source code has approximately 500 million lines totally. The build takes 12 hrs because some of the projects get built more than once in the whole script, and a lot of output binaries are copied to here, there and anywhere, who knows. We are afraid of adding new features (projects) because it requires to update build script and it might cause side-effect. oops, it's totally a mass.

Comment: Thanks, Kendrick. I will check Team City and Cruise first.

Comment: Holy cr*p.  500 million lines?  Really?  Wow.  Sounds like a dedicated staff needs to architect the CM system. Might be worth looking into breaking that up to consider them as separate "products" where the "binaries" produced for some (sub-)systems are considered "products-to-be-used" by other projects. For example, you aren't compiling all of the JVM nor Linux distros when you build -- those are separate products that you merely *use*.  Can you identify internal products (of yours) that you can treat like separate "products" that are not part of the monolithic build?

Comment: Yes, 500m lines. It's kind of the weight of Windows XP. The build takes 3h to compile/link binaries for Windows per CPU architecture (x86 and x64) and 1h for Linux binaries (x64). 2h to create business data. And 3h to create setup bits. Indeed, the completed product is combined with several small and individual products. I'm thinking of breaking them down to separated parts and making part of them not-daily-build.